# Android start service that continue read incoming messages without app start

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, background-service

i want to make an application in which i start service which start broadcast reciever for sms_read and every time when new sms come and reciever detact that message. no matter app is running or not.

Comment: you don't need a service for that. What you need is to register a receiver, and do this on every device boot.

Comment: is it work after app kill?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use a Service for Reading and listening for SMS.

All you need to Do is just register a Broadcast receiver in your Application like this .

```
    <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And just write whatever functionality you have to do upon receiving the SMS in the Broadcast receiver by starting an IntentService or a Thread